# Can I create shared test utilities?

Tags: go

I'm wondering whether it's possible to share test utility code across packages in go.  Specifically, I'm writing a TCP server that will be used by multiple handlers for different message types, and want to reuse a set of common test utils.

The main TCP server code is in `mypkg/tcpserver`:

```
mypkg/tcpserver/tcp_server.go
mypkg/tcpserver/tcp_server_test.go
mypkg/tcpserver/testutils_test.go
```

The `testutils_test.go` code is intended to be a shared library that can be used by `mypkg/tcpserver` and other packages to set up a test server and client for their tests.  For example in the `handler` subpackage I have:

```
mypkg/tcpserver/handler/handler.go
mypkg/tcpserver/handler/csv_handler.go
mypkg/tcpserver/handler/csv_handler_test.go
mypkg/tcpserver/handler/delim_handler.go
mypkg/tcpserver/handler/delim_handler_test.go
```

The `handler/*_test.go` files all import `mypkg/tcpserver`, but they are unable to access the test utilities defined in `mypkg/tcpserver/testutils_test.go`:

```
$ wgo test mypkg/tcpserver/handler
# mypkg/tcpserver/handler
src/mypkg/tcpserver/handler/csv_handler_test.go:37: undefined: tcpserver.CreateTestServer
src/mypkg/tcpserver/handler/csv_handler_test.go:40: undefined: tcpserver.TestSender
FAIL    mypkg/tcpserver/handler [build failed]
```

It appears that tests can import other packages, but not test code defined within those packages?  Is this the intent?  If so, is there an idiomatic way to share test utilities across packages in go?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Create a package containing the testing utilities in non _test.go files. A couple of examples of this approach are [httptest](http://godoc.org/net/http/httptest) and [iotest](http://godoc.org/testing/iotest).

Comment: Darn...I was hoping to avoid having a test package in the main codebase (i.e., shows up in godoc).

Comment: @mmindenhall; you could make it an [internal package](https://golang.org/doc/go1.4#internalpackages), it will currently [still show up godoc](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/internal/) but at least it's more obvious it's internal only and perhaps godoc could gain a feature to filter out internal packages in the future.

Answer (score 16):

If you can't create a testing utilities package (due to docs, dependencies, etc.), try to move testing utiities to a single go file, and add comment `//go:build testing` on the top of the file. Then you can run tests with `go test -tags testing ./...`. This codes won't be contained in `go build` binaries.

See more about go build tags: https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Build_constraints

Comment: This solution works great. It makes possible the sharing of functions across packages for testing purposes only. These function won't be included in the application build.