# Go structures defined from common package in test

Tags: go

This is a packaging question in Go. I have a package schema that looks like this:

`project
|
--- common_test.go
|
--- sub1
|     |
|     --- file.go
|     --- file_test.go
--- sub2
|     |
|     |
|     --- file.go
|     --- file_test.go`

`common_test.go` would look like that:

```
package project
type Test struct {
     ...
}
```

And `sub1` and `sub2` would look like:

```
package sub1
import "project"
func SomeTest(t *testing.T) {
     test := project.Test{}
     ...
}
```

The project package only contains the `common_test.go` file, which defines structures that are used in both `sub1/file_test.go` and `sub2/file_test.go`. But if I try to trigger the test, I get the following error:`no buildable Go source files in project`.

I understand that it is because `common_test.go` includes the `_test` suffix and because it is the only file in the `project` package. But I use the suffix for the reason I don't want this file to be compiled except for test execution.

Is there a way to define test-specific common structures in a package that does not contain non-test files? What is the good practice in this case?

Comment: Duplicate. Also: It is okay to have packages with "test-only code" which is imported during testing. Go is not Java.

Comment: try `go test sub*/*.go`. IMHO im little worried by your package composition, afraid you meet soon a recursive import error, or alike.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I create shared test utilities in go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31794141/can-i-create-shared-test-utilities-in-go)